# How to get top 3 most purchased category list in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, category, category-listing, best-seller

There are modules that get top best selling products list but I want to get the topmost purchased categories list instead of products. Please help me with this. Is there any free module available?

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: No solution yet? :(

Comment: Yes. Do you have any solution?

Comment: Sadly not, I don't want to iterate through all products, as we have a 20k catalog. As this is a main point of one of my customers, we need to work on that. I will keep you up to date, if we have found something :)

Comment: any solution for this?/